# How to design several forms with almost similar look?

Tags: forms, gwt, uibinder

I have about 6 forms to design with UIBinder that look almost the same, the difference is two or three fields. I was thinking about building one form with all the possible fields and hide or show fields depending on the case.

What do you think about this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can work well.  You can define a `BaseForm` class with UiBinder that implements `HasWidgets`, and then define SpecificForm1.ui.xml with something like

```
<custom:BaseForm>
    <g:TextBox ui:field="componentSpecificToThisForm" />
    <g:Button>A button!</g:button>
</custom:BaseForm>
```

and SpecificForm2.ui.xml with something like

```
<custom:BaseForm>
    <g:Label>Something totally different</g:Label>
    <g:Button>A button!</g:button>
</custom:BaseForm>
```

it works great!

Comment: So if I understand your solution, in the BaseForm class I could combine the textBox from SpecificForm1.ui.xml and the Label from SpecificForm2.ui.xml ?

Comment: Sure - add whatever widgets you like.  When you implement `add(IsWidget)` from `HasWidgets`, you can determine how many widgets you'll accept, and what to do with them.  You could also implement `HasOneWidget` and just accept a single HTMLPanel or something.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried something similar, and building one form where I hid/show the appropriate fields was the most simple solution. Another idea would be create a factory, which then builds your form according to your needs.

So, you basically create the components your form is composed of, and the factory wires them together via constructor dependency injection. Worked very well for me, and also has the added benefit that it is very easy to extend your form.

(I'll add an example later).

Comment: Using `HasWidgets` instead of a constructor adds the benefit of using UiBinder files to configure specific versions, which is especially nice if your designer doesn't know Java!